# How can I dynamically change global variable in SCSS in ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC based on theme settings database values & Compile SCSS at run time?

Tags: asp.net-core, sass, themes

What I want to do is dynamically change SASS variables based on values stored in a database & compile SCSS at runtime. I want to provide a theme settings in my project. I don't know if there is a way to set SASS variables from .NET code or js code & compile at run time on theme settings save.

I tried to override SCSS file on theme settings save, but that did not work because after SCSS file change need to compile it but I can't find way how to compile it when project is running.

Thanks in advance!